# Technology Behind BaKoMa Tex

Tags: pdftex, bakoma

I am using BaKoMa Tex recently and I love the technology of real time synchronization they have. I tried to search for their technology but couldn't get much information about it. They some how use latex engines to compile the code but I am unable to understand, how they make the output editable?

If someone here can figure out the tech behind BaKoMa, Please share with me.

Comment: As far as i remember, it uses synctex for source-output-synchronization. Moreover, Synctex was developed for BaKoMa, but was partially integrated into the tex core at some time. "Partially" because standard tex can only sync row-wise, while BaKoMa syncs column-wise, as well.

Comment: @Lupino Thank you for your comment. You answered about the syncing technology of BaKoMa, but I am also curious about the technology it uses to render the contents in preview panel. As far as I know it uses TeX engine to compile source code, but TeX engine normally generates PDF or DVI which are non-editable directly. Then how BaKoMa is able to make them editable in preview panel.

Comment: they don't give away too much information on their website but I assume the mechanism is similar to [AucTeX's preview-latex subsystem](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/features.html).

Comment: BaKoMa TeX uses incremental data processing. It is very different approach in comparison with Preview-LaTeX.